# How to change the value of React-Select using React-Hook-Form

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-select, react-hook-form

- I'm using [**react-hook-form**](https://react-hook-form.com/) to manage my forms
- and also using [**react-select**](https://react-select.com/home) for my select elements

What I want to do is actually very simple but I just couldn't do it and I'm stuck here.

I want to change the value of react-select with external conditions but how do I do this with react-hook-form

The code sample I've written. I want to get the selected value on the radio and set it to react-select

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-controller-v5-forked-ndh54?file=/src/index.jsx

note: if the react-select value changes, the radio does not need to be changed either. the main purpose is to manipulate react-select from radio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer :

react-hook-form use setValue api

https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/setvalue